# In Hive how to get result starting from particular character

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am learning Hive.  Suppose I have table as follows,

```
t1


id  name 
 1   ram
 2   rahim 
 3   yesudas
 4   george 
 5   yogesh
```

Now as in sql I will write,

```
select name
from t1
where name like 'r%'
```

which will give result of name starting from r only as,

```
id  name 
 1   ram
 2   rahim
```

How to achieve this in Hive.Please help

Comment: Pretty much the same query.  Only you'll be referencing your Hive table.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to your title. Instead accept an answer which will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, would you please tell how to accept the answer ,I have just started using stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

**Table Creation:**

```
create table t1 (id int,name string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Query:**

```
select * from t1 where name like 'r%';
```

**Output:**

```
   1 ram
   2 rahim
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same query.

hive>

```
 CREATE TABLE t1(
 id int, 
 name string)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

OK
Time taken: 0.625 seconds

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/amit/data.txt' into table t1;
```

Loading data to table eis_app.t1
Table eis_app.t1 stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=44]
OK
Time taken: 1.22 seconds

```
    hive> select * from t1;

OK
1   ram
2   rahim 
3   yesudas
4   george 
5   yogesh
Time taken: 0.098 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)

hive> select * from t1 where name like 'r%';

    OK
    1   ram
    2   rahim 
    Time taken: 0.107 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
    hive>
```

Comment: Dear Gordon,Amit thank you for your perfect answer.My problem is solved.